# How do I get same scrollbar style for gtk-2.0 and gtk-3.0 apps?

Tags: themes, gtk, gtk3, scrollbar, gtkrc

Sorry for my English mistakes, I'm Spanish.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 in a tablet. I've removed overlay-scrollbars and I have increased the scrollbars size to use them with fingers. In /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc I've changed:

```
GtkScrollbar::slider-width = 23
GtkScrollbar::min-slider-length = 51
```

and added:

```
    GtkScrollbar::has-backward-stepper = 0
    GtkScrollbar::has-forward-stepper = 0
```

In /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css I've changed:

```
    GtkScrollbar-min-slider-length: 51;
    GtkRange-slider-width: 23; (in .scrollbar item)
```

Now my scrollbars are usable with fingers, but they seem different for gtk-2.0 and gtk-3.0 apps. In the picture the left scrollbar is a gtk-2.0 app and the right one is a gtk-3.0

[image: scrollbars]

I want to setup gtk2.0 bar to be exactly the same as gtk3.0, that is

- Make upper and lower extremes empty (oranges circles in the picture)
- Reduce the length of the 3 horizontal lines (black ellipse)

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

---

Hola. Uso ubuntu 11.10 en una tableta; he quitado overlay-scrollbars y he incrementado el tamaño de las barras para poder usarlas con los dedos. Concretamente en /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc be cambiado

```
GtkScrollbar::slider-width = 23
GtkScrollbar::min-slider-length = 51
```

y añadido

```
    GtkScrollbar::has-backward-stepper = 0
    GtkScrollbar::has-forward-stepper = 0
```

En /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css he cambiado

```
    GtkScrollbar-min-slider-length: 51;
    GtkRange-slider-width: 23; (en el apartado.scrollbar)
```

Mis barras son manejables con dedos, pero se ven muy distintas para aplicaciones gtk-2.0 y gtk-3.0. La barra de la izquierda de la imagen es 2.0 y la de la derecha es 3.0

[image: scrollbars]

Quiero configurar las barras 2.0 exactamente como las 3.0, para lo que necesito

- Vaciar los extremos de la barra (círculos naranjas en la imagen)
- Reducir la longitud de las 3 líneas horizontales (elipses negras en la imagen)

¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This isn't quite an answer, but you can always wait a release or two until these inconsistencies are gone...

Comment: If you are still looking for this, in order to remove the gtk2 slider assets use the `contrast = 0.0` in scrollbar murrine engine and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the idea OP, and I'm interested in the answer, but for most uses you can utilize 'natural scrolling' plugins and daemons. You should search for 'natural scrolling' stuff on the web, or if you want you can try Android-X86. It's very fun.