# Why do some windows have these scroll-bars, some these other ones?

Tags: 17.04, themes, gtk, ambiance, radiance

[image]

One thing that nags me is that some windows have these "old school" scroll-bars (depicted left), while other applications have the newer hover-activated ones (right). Can somebody elaborate on **why** this is? I suspect something with GTK2 vs GTK3, right? (I' currently on 17.04, but this applies to earlier versions as well.)

By the way: I don't like both. The left one lacks contrast on the Radiance/Ambiance themes - and I'm constantly searching where the scroll-bar handle is. The other "modern" one, which becomes visible/gets broader on hover, is fiddly and difficult to hit with the mouse. Just my OT 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

It's because some apps use the GTK2 framework, while others have already upgraded to GTK3. GTK versions 2 and 3 pull from different stylesheets/use different layout internals. Compare this answer: [How do I get same scrollbar style for gtk-2.0 and gtk-3.0 apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97388/how-do-i-get-same-scrollbar-style-for-gtk-2-0-and-gtk-3-0-apps?rq=1)